# How can I get an image to resize and fill a table cell regardless of scale

Tags: css, image, resize, stretch

I have a table with multiple cells, and each cell has an image in it, no writing or other, just the images in the cells.
All the images are the correct height and width to make a proper sized image.

I set the height and width of the div, table in the div, the tr and td and the image to 100% height and width, when i drag the window the width scales, but the height does not until it gets bigger than the actual image sizes.

I am guessing that the html/css is taking the height 100% as fixed minimum, and will only stretch greater than the original image height, but the width stretches and shrinks nicely!.
How do i get the height to stretch and shrink like the width?

thanks
All!

Comment: give height in the reference of width eg: `height: 90vw;` this will change the height on width change because while resizing window we only affect width, not height.

Comment: nope, I wish to be able to grab the bottom right corner and drag vertical/horzontal and have the table of images fill the viewing window